# Graph API Facebook in Android using SDK 4.6, returning just id and name of user

Tags: android, facebook

First Button has the following perms, and after I've written the code as is described in the try catch to make the call to Facebook and retrieving data, when click button is pressed. Here there no need to set parameters like another API call.

In the following link shows the implementation too, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

```
loginButtonFacebooK.setReadPermissions(Arrays
            .asList("public_profile"," email",  "user_friends"));


      try {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

                            if( accessToken != null ){

                                GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken,
                                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                                                try {
                                                    String versionApp = GeneralLogic.getVersionName( SplashActivity.this );
                                                    Usuario usuarioNexusDomun = new Usuario(
                                                            object.getString("id"),
                                                            object.getString("first_name"),
                                                            object.getString("last_name"),
                                                            object.getString("name"),
                                                            object.getString("link"),
                                                            object.getString("gender"),
                                                            object.getString("updated_time"),
                                                            token.getToken(),
                                                            versionApp);

                                // here is saving data and just is showing id and name, 
                                // other data is coming null
                    
                                                loginFacebookOk = true;
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        e.getMessage();
                                                }



                                            }

                                        })

                                );

                                batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch batch) {

                                                 if( loginFacebookOk ) {

                                                     gotoMain();

                                                    } else {

                                                     errorMsg(1);

                                                    }
                                    }
                                });



                            }


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.getMessage();
                }
```

Comment: this question has been asked at least a hundred times already. see for "declarative fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: the example code on the page you linked to even includes code for declarative fields...

Comment: I know that exists declarative fields to send as parameters, but if you see, as i said, are different calls. in the link of the example. I am not using GraphRequest Class example, Im using Batch Requests example, and in this call , this call don't let you set the parameters, and doesn't have the method to do it.